# Unable to Parse DateTime in asp.net from excel file of the format - 25-OCT-13 01.08.24.732000000 PM

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel, datetime-conversion

The excel file I am reading has the datetime column value as `"25-OCT-13 01.08.24.732000000 PM"` and to read it into .Net's DateTime format I tried

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(certDate, "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.fffffffff tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out certifiedDateTime)
```

but it always is false. What am i missing.

I am using C# in Visual Studio 2013, .Net 4.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appears you can only have up to 7 `f` elements.

This works:

```
string certDate = "25-Oct-13 01.08.24.7320000 PM";
DateTime certifiedDateTime;
DateTime.TryParseExact(certDate, "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.fffffff tt", 
   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
   System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, 
   out certifiedDateTime);
certifiedDateTime.Dump();
```

It seems this is because DateTime is stored as a 64-bit number representing ticks. There's a good relevant article from Eric Lippert called [Precision and accuracy of DateTime](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/04/08/precision-and-accuracy-of-datetime.aspx).

To get that additional precision you may have to look at a different library. Perhaps Jon Skeet's [Noda Time](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/), though that may not help either.

However, I'm guessing you don't actually want sub-second precision to 9 decimal places (particularly as it's unlikely you have that in the raw data unless the trailing zeroes are a big coincidence).

<s>As such, if you're happy sacrificing this excess precision you could use Regex or similar to parse out the milliseconds and reduce them to 7 digits.</s>

As such, if you're happy sacrificing the excess precision, [MarcinJuraszek's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1163867/marcinjuraszek) comment to use a format including `0` sounds like the best approach:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(certDate, "dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.fffffff00 tt", 
   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
   System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, 
   out certifiedDateTime);
```

Comment: You can also add additional '00' after `fffffff`, but it would require all your input dates ending in zeros: `"dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.fffffff00 tt"`

Comment: Great suggestion - updated answer to include. If you want an upvote feel free to add it as an answer.

Comment: I've started writing my own answer, but then yours appeared and I decided to go with a comment. I'm glad you like my idea!

Comment: Awesome! You both are life savers. I knew there were only 7f's but I didnt know what to replace the next 2f's with. Now I did 0s. Yeah and I dont think we are working at that precision anyway!